# Reducing code verbosity and efficiency

Tags: perl

I came across the below where some heavy stipulations were done, finally we got a number of `@hits` and we need to return just one:

```
if ($#hits > 0)
{
    my $highestScore = 0;
    my $chosenMatch = "";
    for $hit (@hits)
    {
        my $currScore = 0;
        foreach $k (keys %{$hit})
        {
            next if $k eq $retColumn;
            $currScore++ if ($hit->{$k} =~ /\S+/);
        }

        if ($currScore > $highestScore)
        {
            $chosenMatch = $hit;
            $highestScore = $currScore;
        }
    }
    return ($chosenMatch);
}
elsif ($#hits == 0)
{
    return ($hits[0]);
}
```

That's an eye full and I was hoping to simplify the above code, I came up with:

```
return reduce {grep /\S+/, values %{$a} > grep /\S+/, values %{$b} ? $a : $b} @matches;
```

After of using of course `use`ing, [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#$result-=-reduce-)

I wonder if the terse version is any efficient and/or advantage over the original one. Also, there's one condition that's skipped: `if $k eq $retColumn`, how can I efficiently get that in?

Comment: measure the time it takes to execute the first variant. If it is too slow measure the second and if its faster: use it. I would always prefer the first variant because of its readability and comprehensibility

Comment: To fit in the element exclusion, replace `values(%$a)` with `@{$a}{ grep { $_ ne $retColumn } keys(%$a) }`

Comment: Nice ikegami, you're giving me [hash slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)! I tested it, it works! `return reduce {grep /\S/,  @{$a}{grep $_ ne $retColumn, keys %$a} > grep /\S/, @{$b}{grep $_ ne $retColumn, keys %$b} ? $a : $b} @matches;`

Comment: @lzc, Indeed, but I posted it as a comment since I don't recommend it in that form due to readability issues. Readability is what is the most important, so the readability improvements you made and made many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a famous quote:

> "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

It is almost invariably the case that making code more concise really doesn't make much difference to the efficiency, and can cause significant penalties to readability and maintainability.

Algorithm is important, code layout ... isn't really. Things like `reduce`, `map` and `grep` are still looping - they're just doing so behind the scenes. You've gained almost no efficiency by using them, you've just saved some bytes in your file. That's fine if they make your code more clear, but that should be your foremost consideration.

Please - keep things clear first, foremost and always. Make your algorithm good. Don't worry about replacing an explicit loop with a `grep` or `map` unless these things make your code clearer.

And in the interests of being constructive:

- use `strict` and `warnings` is really important. Really really important.

To answer your original question:

> I wonder if the terse version is any efficient and/or advantage over the original one

No, I think if anything the opposite. Short of profiling code speed, the rule of thumb is look at number and size of loops - a single chunk of code rarely makes much difference, but running it lots and lots of times (unnecessarily) is where you get your inefficiency.

In your first example - you have two loops, a `foreach` loop inside a `for` loop. It looks like you traverse your `@hits` data structure once, and 'unwrap' it to get at the inner layers.

In your second example, both your `grep`s are loops, and your `reduce` is as well. If I'm reading it correctly, then it'll be traversing your data structure multiple times. (Because you are `grep`ing `values $a` and `$b` - these will be applied several times).

So I don't think you have gained either readability or efficiency by doing what you've done. But you have made a function that's going to make future maintenance programmers have to think really hard. To take another quote:

> "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" - Brian Kernighan

Comment: Re "the rule of thumb is look at number and size of loops", That's not true at all!!! The number of loops is irrelevant. Your claims that `for (@a) { A }` is more efficient than `for (@a) { B } for (@a) { C }` are wrong. My solution has 5 loops, yet it's as efficient as the one-loop solution. What makes the difference here is the number of times the score is calculated, not how many loops it's spread over.

Comment: Sobrique: You touched on all my question points perfectly! Thanks

Comment: @lzc, Well, he didn't touch the only question you actually asked, and what he said was wrong. Is there a point my answer didn't touch?

Comment: Certainly, I see how `return reduce {grep /\S/,  @{$a}{grep $_ ne $retColumn, keys %$a} > grep /\S/, @{$b}{grep $_ ne $retColumn, keys %$b} ? $a : $b} @matches;` while it works, it certainly re

Comment: @lzc, Your comment was cut short?

Comment: hmm, the 5 minute rule... I accidentally posted too soon... I'll re-post shortly .. but briefly, I'll say @ikegami, thanks for adding life to my question :)

Comment: Certainly Sobrique, I see how `return reduce {grep /\S/,  @{$a}{grep $_ ne $retColumn, keys %$a} > grep /\S/, @{$b}{grep $_ ne $retColumn, keys %$b} ? $a : $b} @matches;` while it works, renders as [write only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language). However, at some point I hope you'll agree that code like `next if grep $key eq $_, @hits;` *reads easier* than it's 10-line counterpart and is one of the reason we love Perl.

Comment: Oh totally. Readability is king. It's rarely worth worrying about efficiency on a modern system - usually the time spent outweighs the runtime of your script. And if it _does_ matter, then the answer is 'profile your code, focus there'. I keep getting into arguments about how 'perl is incomprehensible' and repeatedly point out - I can write bad code in any language. Perl may make it easier, but for all those reasons you can write _good_ code in perl tool.

Answer (score 4):

> I wonder if the terse version is any efficient and/or advantage over the original one

The terse version is less efficient than the original because it calculates the score of every element twice, but it does have readability advantages.

The following keeps the readability gain (and even adds some):

```
sub get_score {
   my ($match) = @_;
   my @keys = grep { $_ ne $retColumn } keys %$match;
   my $score = grep { /\S/ } @{$match}{ @keys };
   return $score;
}

return reduce { get_score($a) > get_score($b) ? $a : $b } @matches;
```

You can look at any part of that sub and understand it without looking around. The least context you need to understand code, the more readable it is.

If you did need an efficiency boost, you can avoid calling `get_score` on every input twice by using a Schwartzian Transform. As with many optimizations, you will take a readability hit, but at least it's idiomatic (well known and thus well recognizable).

```
return
   map { $_->[0] }
   reduce { $a->[1] > $b->[1] ? $a : $b }
   map { [ $match, get_score($match) ] }
   @matches;
```

Comment: Would `Memoize`ing `get_score` be worth considering in the first example? Looks like a good place to cache results.